# How to get arbitrary fields from dynamic array using MAP function in excel formulas?

Tags: excel-formula

In excel document i have data table **ExpensesData** with columns: *date, provider, amount*

I have to display it on another sheet filtering by date

I did it successfully using the following formula

```
=LET(
data;
FILTER(INDIRECT("ExpensesData"); (INDIRECT("ExpensesData[date]") >= I3) * (INDIRECT("ExpensesData[date]") <= J3));
data
)
```

So i get exactly the same table but filtered by date

Now what if i want to transform a little bit original table and for example remove column *provider*, so only *date* and *amount* should be displayed on another sheet

I had an idea i can do it using something like

```
MAP(data; LAMBDA(v; {v[date]; v[amount]}))
```

But it doesn't work. Can you please give me a tip how to get arbitrary fields from existing table using MAP function ?

Comment: `CHOOSECOLS()` will be useful as it seems! Try: `=LET(data,FILTER(INDIRECT("ExpensesData"), (INDIRECT("ExpensesData[date]") >= B2) * (INDIRECT("ExpensesData[date]") <= C2)),CHOOSECOLS(data,1,3))` If you want random columns then in place of `1` and `3` use this `RANDARRAY(1,2,1,3,1)`

Comment: Why use indirect (and LET) if you know the exact reference: `=FILTER(ExpensesData;(ExpensesData[date]>=I3)*(ExpensesData[date]<=J3))` This works as well, right? This makes it non-volatile

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, yes, thanks, and how to transform this into arbitrary array based on this table using MAP

Comment: @P.b It was just an example, my goal is to create another values based on original data, not just choose columns. But thank you for this function.

Comment: @DmitryReutov when you can do it without `LAMBDA()` then why do you want to you use a `LAMBDA()` helper function?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, i am okay about any way - with lambda or without. Any example how to create arbitrary values based on original data will be very helpful for me. I tried my best in google but didn't manage.

Comment: @DmitryReutov then i have already commented in the first, can you try that one?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, as i wrote above there are more complicated problem then just swap columns, i did it just for example. Lets say we don't know this function, can be the problem be solved other way ?

Comment: Well I don't understand your goal. If you could provide some samples to illustrate your goal than I can look into it, but right now I'm left in the dark

Comment: @P.b lets say out of original table (date, provider, amount) i want to get table on another sheet with columns: date amount1 amount2... Where amount1 is equal amount if provider = Coca cola otherwise 0, and where amount2 is equal to amount if provider is pepsi cola otherwise 0. If you can provide an example would be very very helpful

Comment: Use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to post some sample data in your question which we can copy and paste in Excel. Also provide the expected result with that sample, because you know your data and talking about it makes perfect sense to you, but I don't know your data structure.

Comment: @DmitryReutov it worked with `MAP()` but it makes no sense to involve a `LAMBDA()` helper here. Anyways you could try this without existing data : `=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(ExpensesData,MAP(ExpensesData[Date],LAMBDA(x,(I3>=x)*(x<=J3)))),1,3)` as you can already do as shown by P.b sir

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get MAP working.
But FILTER and CHOOSECOLS works:

1. Filter the data
2. Choose your columns

---

```
=LET(
   data, FILTER(ExpensesData, (ExpensesData[date] >= I3) * (ExpensesData[date] <= J3)),
   CHOOSECOLS(data, {1,3})
)
```

---

see [image: screenshot]

**UPDATE**:
The easiest way to do the transformation with **MAP** and **LAMBDA**, assuming the filtered columns don't change, would be by using the formula separately for the filtered columns with the same filter.

for example: if you want the amount squared, do the following for the amount column:

```
=LET(
   filteredData, FILTER(ExpensesData, (ExpensesData[date] >= I3) * (ExpensesData[date] <= J3)),
   CHOOSECOLS(MAP(filteredData,LAMBDA(a,a*a)),3)
)
```

see [image: Screenshot 2]

The date column without any changes would be :

```
=LET(
   filteredData, FILTER(ExpensesData, (ExpensesData[date] >= I3) * (ExpensesData[date] <= J3)),
   CHOOSECOLS(filteredData, 1)
)
```

see [image: Screenshot 3]

Its definitely not the best solution so far, but I hope it helps you find a better one.

Comment: @P.b My answer was a little bit rushed. Sorry for that. I updated the answer using MAP and LAMBDA. 
It is difficult to answer Dmitry's question as it lacks a concret definition of the use case.

Comment: sorry, I mistaken you for the person posing the question. I'll delete my comment. I agree on the lack of a concrete use case.